# Laravel 6 - CSS file transferred to public folder

Tags: php, css, font-awesome, laravel-6

Hello everyone I'm new to Laravel, just a quick question. I copied the folder of bootstrap sb-admin-2 theme into my laravel public folder. For some reason this syntax works

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/theme/vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

But if I moved the all.css file into the public/css folder

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/all.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

this doesn't work, icons are displayed as torn paper. Why is that? It doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

you need to create assets folder in your public file. your css file path will be public/assets/css/all.css.

when using `asset('css/all.css')` the url will be :

```
`http://localhost/assets/img/photo.jpg`
```

you can configure your assets url from `.env` file using `ASSET_URL`
example:

```
ASSET_URL=http://localhost/assets_test
```

Answer (score -1):

make sure your file is inside the css folder

css / all.css

Comment: "_But if I moved the all.css file into the public/css folder_"